# Is it a good idea to keep Request querystring as a property?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code snippet is like this:

```
public static string EventId
{
    get { return HttpContext.Current.Request["eventId"]; }
}
```

And I will call this property `EventId` whenever I need it. Is it a good practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you guarantee that `eventId` will never change? If so it might not be a bad idea, but this comes down to a few things

- `eventId` never changes;
- how and where you're using it. It might be somewhat difficult for a new programmer in the project to locate and realize what it actually does (it returns the `eventId` for the current Http Request), solely based on the property name; and
- Are you sure that both `HttpContext.Current` and `Current.Request` are initialized before retrieving `eventId`. There is a change these will throw a null reference exception. It might be a very good idea to do a simple `if != null` check before invoking the Request property.

If your code can accommodate for these points I don't see any inherently wrong with doing this.